# ActiveModel query returns nil unless run in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel, actioncontroller

In my controller action I am making a very simple query based on a token:

```
def info
  @order = Order.find_by_token(params['token'])

  raise 'Not found' unless @order # Debugging
end
```

This raises an exception and the `@order` object seems to be `nil`. However, if I run the exact same query in the console. I get a result:

[image: Problem]

I frankly have no clue why the query would result in `nil` just to return an object when I try it in the console.

`routes.rb`:

```
get 'info/:token' => 'orders#info', as: 'info'
```

Comment: How is your console running? There's no debugger near that line of code, so it's getting loaded in a different environment, somehow. Why not insert a `binging.pry`, or `byebug`, or whatever, **on line 22 of the controller** and see what the valid of `params['token']` etc is?

Comment: Also, is it possible that you've done something "unusual" - like update the gems, or perform a database migration, and *not restarted the server*? If so, do that.